# Optimal fan configuration for two self-contained water coolers

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, fan, cooling

So I got a new graphics card, the EVGA 980ti hybrid (has its own self contained water cooler), as well as a new case the NZXT H440. I'm trying to think of optimal airflow.

My CPU is cooled with a self contained water cooling unit (corsair h60). I figured I'd have the corsair H60 for the cpu at the back exhausting air, and that only leaves one of the two top fan mounts for the EVGA cooler. Should that be exhausting air or taking air in? Or should one of the top fans be exhausting and the other taking air in? Considering the front three fans on the case will be taking air in. Conversely should I switch around the CPU cooler and EVGA setup?

I've read that its best to have more exhaust than intake for negative pressure.

Answer (score 1):

People will have different opinions on whether to have negative or positive pressure within your case. I now have positive having switched from negative, which means I am not sucking in dust particles from every crack in my case. (the dust was unbearable as it would clog after a week and I would have to clean my rads with negative)

I switched my top rad fans to intake and after that it was fine. Most of the dust was getting caught in the dust filters and not coming through small gaps in my case which was good.

That is from personal experience. Although people may say "hot air rises so have your fans at the top exhaust". It does not matter as long as you have your intake fans at the front blowing that hot air to the back towards your exhaust.

The best option? Why not try positive first, then if you feel there is a lot of dust, switch them around. (although having positive first "should" be the better option).

Note: I have a volume area in my case. Such as the NZXT H440 should have. And I have the same configuration as you apart from the exhaust not having a rad.